# Port DjangoCMS - Project to another machine

Tags: django, django-cms

I recently made a Website based on DjangoCMS for a project I had to do in school. I also integrated a blog- app which I had made earlier in Django.

When I tried porting the project to another machine though, I get an error message saying "App 'blog/' could not be found. Is it in `INSTALLED_APPS`?" Also, my whole content is gone.No menus, content, pages, nothing. My DB is SQlite3

I ran the project with makemigrations blog, makemigrations website (that's what the cms-project is called) followed by runserver.

So basically my question would be: What can I do to fix this? Is there any way to make something like an identical copy of my existing project on another machine?

Comment: just copy the app and the sqlitefile in it's entirity to the new server

Comment: I tried that,, it didn't work. I keep everything in a git repo, code as well as the  db. So this should be simply a matter of cloning the repo migrate and runserver, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: If you copy everything migrations are not needed. And please also explain what didn't work means (what errors etc).

Comment: So this should basically only mean git clone - activate virtualenv runserver, correct? Because if I do that I get an error: return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
OperationalError: no such table: cms_urlconfrevision

Comment: Okay, so far i can access the site, but I have to manually create pages and assign them the corresponding templates, also my content, navigation structure and the rest is gone.

Comment: That means your local copy of the database doesnt' have that data either.

Comment: Well. That's a bummer. Another thing. I noticed that some of the backend looks different on my laptop compared to my PC at home on which I did the main development and which hosts the working version. Does DjangoCMS care which version is installed if I port the Project. Or could it just have upgraded itself at some point on my Laptop, thus destroying links, dependencies and the likes?

Comment: Your last comment is not clear at all

Comment: I figured out what the problem was, it was indeed the database, I didn't copy it. Thanks for the help nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

**VirtualEnv** will be good for you, i was doing the same thing, make your virtualenv relocatable with `virtualenv venv_folder --relocatable`, then move project folder and virtualenv folder to new server(you can use scp for transfering files over ssh).Just activate virtualenv again and runserver on your new place. >> `source venv_folder/bin/activate; python manage.py runserver`